# provisioning_oauth_example in gdata-python: 2-legged and 3-legged errors

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, oauth-2.0, gdata-python-client

I am tying to run [provisionin_oauth_example](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/samples/apps/#apps/provisioning_oauth_example) from gdata-python-client library examples.

After some minor changes mainly to make it work in AppEngine, that's what happens in both local and AppEngine server:

If I use OAuth domain key:

- With **2-legged authorization**, I get:

  > Unknown Authorization Header.
  >
  > Error 401
- With **3-legged authorization**, I can list all users from my GApps domain using an admin user. That's the only thing that actually works.

If I use Consumer key and secret from Marketplace:

- With **2-legged authorization**, I get:

  > Invalid OAuth signature
  >
  > Error 403
- With **3-legged authorization** I get caught into a exception:

> ...
>    File "/base/data/home/apps/s~deimos-intranet/1.363589987091160356/main.py", line 147, in post
>      scopes=INIT['SCOPES'], oauth_callback=self.request.uri)
>    File "/base/data/home/apps/s~deimos-intranet/1.363589987091160356/gdata/service.py", line 429, in FetchOAuthRequestToken
>
> raise FetchingOAuthRequestTokenFailed(error)
>
> FetchingOAuthRequestTokenFailed: {'status': 400L, 'body': 'signature_invalid\nbase_string:GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2FOAuthGetRequestToken&oauth_callback%*XXXXXX*oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1354489805%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fapps-apis.google.com%252Fa%252Ffeeds\n\n', 'reason': 'Non 200 response on fetch request token'}

Does anybody know why 2-legged auth is not working at all, and why 3 legged is not working with app key, even if I had authorized all the feeds needed to access data?

I get caught some days ago and now I got no hints searching around.

Thank you so much.